# Is asking questions about movie industry details on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

More specifically, is this question on-topic?

> How can I find out the means for contacting [Ben Burtt](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0123785/)? E.g. his agent, etc...

I tried the obvious (LinkedIn, Twitter/Facebook, IMDB) approaches.

Comment: For that specific?  Instant ***no*** comes to mind.  For a general case, I still don't see it on-topic.

Comment: @TylerShads - I'm perfectly happy to ask a generic "what is the proper procedure to contact a famous person working on movies, for whom no public contact info is known". Basically, is there official place to find soeone's agents? Is there protocol for approaching? My bigger worry/suspicion was whether this is off-topic because it is about the industry and not movie contents.

Comment: BTW, the context is that we have plenty of questions on SFF.SE that require asking people in the industry (e.f. Ben Burtt for one of them). Some have twitters, most are not obviously reachable.

Comment: The address listed for him in Marquis Biographies online is: LucasArts PO Box 29908 San Francisco CA 94129-0908. This database may be available through larger public libraries and many university libraries.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about industry details, but trying to find personal contact information for individuals is strictly off-topic to me.

Comment: I don't think a name of a Hollywood figure's agent/publicist is something that is typically considered a personal and non-public detail?

Comment: @DVK I think the point is *anything* regarding solicitation of personal details of *any* individual without that individual's permission is more privacy concerns than anything.

Comment: @TylerShads - Definitely agree with that. My point was that people in hollywood seem to make "who my agent/publicist is" **public**, non-personal information, on purpose. Meaning there can't be privacy concerns.